# How do I modify the question format but keep the question text on the same line?

Tags: exam, format

I want to modify my question numbering so it appears like `1.1.`, `1.2`, `1.3.` and so on. This can easily be done by `\qformat{\thequestion.\thesection.}`. However, this causes the question text to be displaced to the next line. From the exam package documentation,

> The default setup is for the question number to appear in the left margin and for the text of
> the question to begin on that line. It’s possible to change this so that the text of the question
> starts on the line following the question number, and the format of the line containing the
> question number is determined by the user.

My question is, *how do I modify the question format while keeping the default behavior*, wherein the question numbers appears in the left margin and the text of the question begins on the same line?

Comment: Instead of what you did, try `\renewcommand\questionlabel{\thesection.\thequestion.}`.